# Currying in inversed order in python

Tags: python, currying, toolz

Suppose I have a function like this:

```
from toolz.curried import *

@curry
def foo(x, y):
    print(x, y)
```

Then I can call:

```
foo(1,2)
foo(1)(2)
```

Both return the same as expected.

However, I would like to do something like this:

```
@curry.inverse # hypothetical
def bar(*args, last):
    print(*args, last)

bar(1,2,3)(last)
```

The idea behind this is that I would like to pre-configure a function and then put it in a pipe like this:

```
pipe(data,
    f1, # another function
    bar(1,2,3) # unknown number of arguments
)
```

Then, `bar(1,2,3)(data)` would be called as a part of the pipe. However, I don't know how to do this. Any ideas? Thank you very much!

**Edit:**

A more illustrative example was asked for. Thus, here it comes:

```
import pandas as pd
from toolz.curried import *

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def filter_columns(*args, df):
    return df[[*args]]

pipe(df,
    transformation_1,
    transformation_2,
    filter_columns("date", "temperature")
)
```

As you can see, the DataFrame is piped through the functions, and `filter_columns` is one of them. However, the function is pre-configured and returns a function that only takes a DataFrame, similar to a decorator. The same behaviour could be achieved with this:

```
def filter_columns(*args):
    def f(df):
        return df[[*args]]
    return f
```

However, I would always have to run two calls then, e.g. `filter_columns()(df)`, and that is what I would like to avoid.

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: so for `foo(1,2)` and `foo(1)(2)` you want that it print `2 1` ??

Comment: @amirouche Python 3.5.1

Comment: @Copperfield Not exactly, I want to provide an unknown number of arguments first to "configure" my function, and afterwards I'd like to pass another positional argument that is read by `pipe`. As far as I know, this cannot be a keyword argument.

Comment: can you put a more illustrative example of the desire behavior ?

Comment: @Copperfield Please see above :-) Does that help?

Comment: oh right, the pipe come from that import *, those always annoy me because I don't know what I have... let me rethink me answer with the new update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well I am unfamiliar with toolz module, but it looks like there is no easy way of curry a function with arbitrary number of arguments, so lets try something else.

First as a alternative to

```
def filter_columns(*args):
    def f(df):
        return df[*args]
    return f
```

(and by the way, `df[*args]` is a syntax error )

to avoid `filter_columns()(data)` you can just grab the last element in `args` and use the slice notation to grab everything else, for example

```
def filter_columns(*argv):
    df, columns = argv[-1], argv[:-1]
    return df[columns]
```

And use as `filter_columns(df)`, `filter_columns("date", "temperature", df)`, etc.

And then use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to construct your new, well partially applied, filter to build your pipe like for example

```
from functools import partial
from toolz.curried import pipe # always be explicit with your import, the last thing you want is import something you don't want to, that overwrite something else you use

pipe(df,
    transformation_1,
    transformation_2,
    partial(filter_columns, "date", "temperature")
)
```

Comment: Right, I see that this works with your `pipe` definition; however, it's where I am struggling when using the pipe from `toolz`.

Comment: Wonderful! I didn't think of `df, columns = argv[-1], argv[:-1]`. How simple and elegant!